# Hide all elements except one div for print view

Tags: css

I have the following CSS for my print style:

```css
* {
 display:none;
}

#printableArea {
 display:block;
}
```

I expected this to hide *all* elements, and only show the printableArea, however *everything* gets hidden. In print view, all I get is a blank page.

I have it included properly in the HEAD, with `media="print"` on this particular stylesheet.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If an element is not displayed, then none of its children will be displayed (no matter what their display property is set to).

`*` matches the `<html>` element, so the entire document is hidden.

You need to be more selective about what you hide.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I guess I could just place printableArea outside of the page wrapper, then hide the wrapper, showing the print div.

Comment: @FatherCarbon - that's what I've just implemented and it looks like it'll do the trick nicely

Answer (score 27):

You're taking the right general approach, but you want to use `visibility: hidden` instead of `display: none` so that you can set child elements to be visible.

See [Print <div id=printarea></div> only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468881/print-div-id-printarea-div-only)

Answer (score 12):

*Answering because I found this question while searching for this*

Instead of 'display: none' you can use :

```
* {
  visibility: hidden;
  margin:0; padding:0;
}

#printableArea * {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

source : https://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/5-7-discussion/need-to-print-a-certain-div-and-ignore-everythign-else-on-the-pa

Comment: This works but how do you make it so the `#printableArea` moves to the top left of the paper instead of retaining it's position in the HTML/CSS structure retained by using `visibility:hidden`?

Comment: I did not have that issue when removing margins and padding. Altho, if you want it to the left, make sure it's aligned to the left? You coud always make it float or change it's position to absolute. Also, if you follow the link, someone uses `display: none` on specific classes. The issue here is that if you do it on `*` selector t will hide everything, including what you want tp print.

Comment: Using `display: none` on certain classes is what I eventually ended up doing.  It's not as "universal" as I would prefer but it will work for the time being.

Answer (score 11):

```
html body * {
 display:none;
}

#printableArea {
 display:block;
}
```

Also, you may need an !important on #printableArea, but probably not.

Comment: This will only work if #printableArea is a direct child of body.

Answer (score 8):

You might try popping it up on top of everything.  This solved 90% of my problems, then I just had to make a `.noprint` class and add it to a few straggling elements.

```
.print_area{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;

    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: this didn't hide everything else on my 1st try.

Comment: I can't scroll down or up !

Comment: @Salem WOW! What kid of paper are you printing on?

Comment: If you are printing something that spans wider or taller than the paper, it will not print on to the next page.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use JavaScript, you can try this simple snippet that doesn't even require jQuery:

```
document.body.innerHTML=document.getElementById('printableArea').innerHTML;
```

Comment: this action will replace the entire HTML, not a required result

Comment: it's also likely to break things.

Comment: Worked for me right out of the box, with no problems. Same site caused issues for the CSS methods offered. One of the simplest methods offered.

Answer (score 1):

make a div wrap everything after the body tag. Before the wrap div, put the visible item's div.

I had to do this to make a simple username-password page, and needed to hide everything, except the half-opaque sign-in form's background. So, after the correct credentials were typed in, the form would animate out, and the half-opaque page cover would animate out, and finally, EVERYTHING aside would show up and you could use the page normally.

Answer (score 1):

```css
@media print {
    * {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    /* Show element to print, and any children he has. */
    .svgContainer, .svgContainer * {
        visibility: initial;
    }
}
```

Make sure any children elements are also visible. Remember that invisible elements still influence positionning of other elements in the page. In my (simple) case, I just added `position: fixed;` on `.svgContainer` (somewhere else).

Answer (score 1):

There is another clean way to achieve this:

```
* {
    visibility: hidden;
}

#printableArea {
    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

That way you're going to get only the `#printableArea` element in the print view and all of the other elements will be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

There is a one-line solution:

**With JQuery**

```
var selector = '';
$(document.head).append($('style').text('*{visibility:hidden}' + selector + '{visibility:visible}'));
```

**Without JQuery**

```
var selector = '';
document.head.appendChild(Object.assign(document.createElement('style'), { innerText: '*{visibility:hidden}' + selector + '{visibility:visible}' });
```

In both examples, set the `selector` variable to the selector you want. For example, `div#page:hover` or `p.class1,p.class2`

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use the following code and assign "hide" class to that specific element you dont want to display on print page

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
    img
    {
        display:none;
    }
    .hide
    {
        display:none;
    }

</style>
```