# print DIV not page

Tags: javascript, printing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Print <div id=printarea></div> only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468881/print-div-id-printarea-div-only)

Hi all,

We all know `window.print()`.

Let us assume we have a div with some content in it. How can we print it?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [jQuery Print Element v1.2](http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/). This would obviously require the inclusion of the [jQuery JS file](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery) in your project. As `MattP` pointed out, it can be done without jQuery and an extra plugin, but I always lean toward jQuery for cross-browser compatibility.

**HTML**

```
<div id="printDiv">Content to be printed</div>
```

**JS/jQuery**

```
$('#printDiv').printElement();
```