# How to print only a selected HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to implement a print feature in HTML. I know I can print the whole page with `window.print()`, but how do I print only a specific page element? For example a particular `<DIV>Some text to print</DIV>`.

Comment: The same question has been asked before:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468881/print-div-id-printarea-div-only

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print <div id="printarea"></div> only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468881/print-div-id-printarea-div-only)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You could use a print specific CSS stylesheet and hide everything but what you want printed.

`<div class="no-print">I won't print</div><div class="something-else">I will!</div>`

Just the `no-print` class will be hidden, but anything with a print class will show.

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
   .no-print { display: none; }
</style>
```

Comment: Hi manyxcxi, Any small example of doing this the CSS way? This <DIV> is a nested <DIV> many layers down.

Comment: The syntax for this is as follows: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css" /> - this tells the browser that when it send the page to the print spool, it should use that CSS instead.

Comment: Superstringcheese, thanks for explaining. But this solution entails that I have to add 'class="no-print"' to 10's of <DIV>'s on my page. Correct?

Comment: Give the DIV an ID and refer to that in your print stylesheet. Set: body * {display:none;} and then #myDiv {display:normal;} (override the style only on that div). What you're doing is setting everything to invisible by default, then specifying the individual overrides you want.

Comment: O ok.. got it. Will try to work on it.. in case I get stuck somewhere.. will post back

Comment: @Superstringcheese `display: normal` doesn't exist. I wish there was a generic option to turn on elements

Comment: @th3an0maly 'normal' meaning a normal option for that context: block, inline, etc. Sorry for the confusion. Probably most elements will be block. It's not elegant, but it will work. I normally take the approach of hiding what I *don't* want.

Comment: @ashurexm is this still the valid way to implement print styles? also like such `<link rel="stylesheet" media="mediatype and|not|only (expressions)" href="print.css">`?

Comment: @user2230470 That was an example of an inline style that's for print only. If you had an entire print only stylesheet you would want to do exactly as you've described using the `media` attribute on the stylesheet link.

Comment: @ashurexm like, `media="print"` i know

Comment: This is not an accepted answer for me because the element in want to print is inside an other element. The other contents of that element i don't want to print

Answer (score 13):

If you are familiar to jQuery, you can use [jQuery Print Element](http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/) plugin like this:

```
$('SelectorToPrint').printElement();
```

Comment: Is there a vanilla rendition of this?

Comment: This does not work out of the box with newer jquery versions because it uses the "jQuery.browser" property that was removed. jQuery Doc says: _This property was removed in jQuery 1.9 and is available only through the jQuery.migrate plugin. Please try to use feature detection instead._

Comment: i love jquery, all you need is search a plugin.

Comment: @Softsofter this is exactly the reason why I don't like jQuery, you don't use your own logic to solve a problem, and once jQuery breaks or a plugin is out of date, you just don't know how to fix a certain situation. Better learn the depth of your browser if you want to be autonomous.

Answer (score 11):

Created something generic to use on any HTML element

```js
HTMLElement.prototype.printMe = printMe;
function printMe(query){
  var myframe = document.createElement('IFRAME');
  myframe.domain = document.domain;
  myframe.style.position = "absolute";
  myframe.style.top = "-10000px";
  document.body.appendChild(myframe);
  myframe.contentDocument.write(this.innerHTML) ;
  setTimeout(function(){
  myframe.focus();
  myframe.contentWindow.print();
  myframe.parentNode.removeChild(myframe) ;// remove frame
  },3000); // wait for images to load inside iframe
  window.focus();
 }
```

Usage:

```
document.getElementById('xyz').printMe();
document.getElementsByClassName('xyz')[0].printMe();
```

Hope this help
Regards
Gaurav Khurana

Comment: This ignore styles sheets styles.

Answer (score 7):

I found a solution that doesn't have the problems other solutions have. It copies the printed element to the body, and is fairly elegant and general:

CSS:

```
@media print {
  body *:not(.printable, .printable *) {
    // hide everything but printable elements and their children
    display: none;
  }
}
```

JS:

```
function printElement(e) {
  let cloned = e.cloneNode(true);
  document.body.appendChild(cloned);
  cloned.classList.add("printable");
  window.print();
  document.body.removeChild(cloned);
}
```

The only limitation is that the element loses styles it inherited from its previous parents. But it works on arbitrary elements in the document structure

Comment: This seems far superior to a lot of the other solutions - it's fast, efficient, and maintains styling from the global scope of the page. As you say, the only limitation is that you can't rely on cascading styling rules from whatever elements the printable area was contained within, but that's a minor thing, and most of the other solutions don't support this either.

Answer (score 5):

Simple html and pure javascript works best. Parameter "this" refers to current id, so that function is universal for all ids. By using "ref.textContent" instead of "ref.innerHTML" you can extract only textual content for printing.

html body:

```
<div id="monitor" onclick="idElementPrint(this)">element to print
<img src="example.jpg" width="200">
</div>
```

pure javascript:

```
/*or:
monitor.textContent = "click me to print content";

const imga = new Image(200); //width
imga.src = "./example.jpg";
monitor.appendChild(imga);
*/

const idElementPrint = ref => {
  const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  iframe.style.display = "none";
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  const pri = iframe.contentWindow;
  pri.document.open();
  pri.document.write(ref.innerHTML);
  pri.document.close();
  pri.focus();
  pri.print();
  pri.onafterprint = () => { document.body.removeChild(iframe); }
}
```

Comment: Super clean answer, you may want to remove the element after : `pri.onafterprint = () => { document.body.removeChild(ifram); }`

Comment: This worked, thanks!, but it is ignoring the CSS. do you know why? some sugestions?

Comment: This only prints the **text** content of the element - no markup is preserved, which is not what most people are looking for. Swapping to `document.write(ref.innerHTML)` would work better.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using bootstrap, just add classname d-print-none to the elements you don't want to display in print

Comment: that's nice info ...

Answer (score 2):

If you are using JQuery, you can use [clone](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) to do the following:

```
function printElement(e) {
  var ifr = document.createElement('iframe');
  ifr.style='height: 0px; width: 0px; position: absolute'
  document.body.appendChild(ifr);

  $(e).clone().appendTo(ifr.contentDocument.body);
  ifr.contentWindow.print();

  ifr.parentElement.removeChild(ifr);
}
```

and use like so:
`printElement(document.getElementById('myElementToPrint'))`

Comment: hmm, adding stylesheets manually, but it still prints it without any style

Comment: can you send example to recreate/illustrate?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you well you can use CSS3 to print your selected HTML element.

```css
@media print {
  body.print-element *:not(.print) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Notice, that you just need a selector. This allows you to easily print an element or the entire page using CSS classes.

Here you can check a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/gengns/d50m8ztu/

Comment: This only works for direct children of `body`: if `.print` is not a direct child of `body`, all of its parents get `display: none` and are hidden. See https://jsfiddle.net/bzf92rj3/

Answer (score 1):

If you need to print the HTML element with pure JS, you can open a window that contains only the element you want to print (without any HTML-markup).

For instance, you can print the image itself without wrapping it in any HTML by opening this image in a new window as a file.

Note: 'visible=none' doesn't actually make the window invisible, but it allows to open it as a separate window (not a tab).

afterprint event allows us to close the window when the printing dialog is closed. event.target points to the opened window instance.

Note: afterprint MUST be assigned before calling .print(), otherwise it would not be called.

```
let win = window.open('/absolute/image/path.jpg', '__blank', 'visible=none');
win.addEventListener('afterprint', event => event.target.close() );
win.print();
```

Answer (score 0):

Printing an Html or a Selected Html is easy using Print.Js
Add Print.Js Library

```
http://printjs.crabbly.com/

  <form method="post" action="#" id="printJS-form">
    ...
  </form>

 <button type="button" onclick="printJS('printJS-form', 'html')">
    Print Form
 </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it is:

```
elem = document.getElementById('elem').outerHTML

orig = document.documentElement.outerHTML

document.documentElement.outerHTML=elem
print()

document.documentElement.outerHTML = orig
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this method

```
function printDiv(divName) {   
        let specific_element = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
        let original_elements = document.body.innerHTML;
    
        document.body.innerHTML = specific_element;
        window.print();
        document.body.innerHTML = original_elements;
    }
```

Comment: The biggest problem I see with this approach is that all the event listeners from original elements will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

This implementation will create and apply an ad-hoc temporary style that hides all the elements on print media except the one that we want to print. After the printing the temporary style is removed, so your document will get back to its initial state.

Feel free to adjust the ad-hoc style (like papar size, margins, etc) to fit your needs.

```js
/**
 * @description Print the given element using browser built-in function
 * @param {HTMLElement} element
 */
function printElement(element) {
  if (!element) {
    throw new Error(`Invalid print target element`);
  }

  const printWrapper = "print-wrapper";
  const printElement = "print-element";
  const css = `
  body.${printWrapper} *:not(.${printElement}) {
    visibility:hidden;
  }
  body.${printWrapper} .${printElement} {
    width: 210mm;
    height: 297mm;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    position:fixed;
  }
  body.${printWrapper} .${printElement} * {
    visibility:initial;
    margin: 0;
  }
  `;

  const head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
  const style = document.createElement("style");

  style.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
  style.setAttribute("media", "print");

  if (style.styleSheet) {
    style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
  } else {
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
  }

  head.appendChild(style);

  document.body.classList.add(printWrapper);
  element.classList.add(printElement);

  window.print();

  document.body.classList.remove(printWrapper);
  element.classList.remove(printElement);

  head.removeChild(style);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  function printDomElement(element) {
    element.classList.add("printCss");

    let printId = "printSvgId";
    let name = ".printCss";
    let rules = "-webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;height:100%;width:100%;position:fixed;top:0;left:0;margin:0;";

    var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.id = printId;
    style.media = "print";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);

    if (!(style.sheet || {}).insertRule)(style.styleSheet || style.sheet).addRule(name, rules);
    else style.sheet.insertRule(name + "{" + rules + "}", 0);

    window.print();

    setTimeout(() => {
      element.classList.remove("printCss");
      let elem = document.getElementById(printId);
      if (elem) elem.remove();
    }, 500);

  }
```

Comment: Good answers include some explanation, not just a block of code.

Answer (score 0):

The example below is where you can click on a button, like with `Button 1` text, and ONLY that button will appear. Some notes about my solution which was tested on my Mac including on Safari, Firefox, Chrome, and Edge browsers:

- When a `button` tag is clicked:

  - **`hideAllElemsOnPrint`** JS function:
    All HTML elements (excluding the `html` tag) have a `.hide-print` class added that hides elements with a `@media print {...}` media query in the CSS with `display: none;`
  - **`onPrintEvents`** and **`updateParentElemClasses`** JS functions:
    ONLY the `button` tag that is clicked (and all parent tags that enclose the this `button` tag) have the `.hide-print` class removed and `.show-print` class added
  - The `.show-print` class does NOTHING but make my code easier to debug and has no styles in the CSS
  - **`exitPrintEvents`** JS function:
    Runs when you see the print dialogue popup and AFTER you click on the `Cancel` or `Print` buttons in the dialogue and `.show-print` and `.hide-print` classes are removed from all elements

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('button');

function onPrintEvents(btns, showPrintClass, hidePrintClass) {  
  btns.forEach((btn) => {    
   btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {     
    const allElems = document.querySelectorAll('*');
    hideAllElemsOnPrint(allElems);   
     
    const currentBtn = e.target;
    currentBtn.classList.remove('hide-print'); 
    currentBtn.classList.add('show-print');
     
    updateParentElemClasses(currentBtn, showPrintClass, hidePrintClass);
    window.print();
   });
  });  
}

function exitPrintEvents(showPrintClass, hidePrintClass) {
  const afterPrint = function () {
    const printableElemsArr = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(showPrintClass));
    const notPrintableElemsArr = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(hidePrintClass));
    
    const elems = [...printableElemsArr, ...notPrintableElemsArr];
    
    elems.forEach((elem) => {
      elem.classList.remove(showPrintClass);
      elem.classList.remove(hidePrintClass);
    });
  };

  const mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');

  mediaQueryList.addListener(function (e) {
    if (!e.matches) {
      afterPrint();
    }
  });
}

function updateParentElemClasses(elem, addClass, removeClass) {
  let getParent = elem.parentNode;
  getParent.classList.add(addClass);
  getParent.classList.remove(removeClass);
  let parentNodeName = getParent.nodeName.toUpperCase();

  while(parentNodeName) {    
    if(parentNodeName === 'BODY' || !parentNodeName) {
      break;
    }

    getParent = getParent.parentNode;
    getParent.classList.add(addClass);
    getParent.classList.remove(removeClass);
    parentNodeName = getParent?.nodeName.toUpperCase();     
  }  
}

function hideAllElemsOnPrint(allElems) {
  allElems.forEach((elem) => {
    const nodeTag = elem.nodeName.toUpperCase();

    if(nodeTag !== 'HTML') {
      elem.classList.remove('show-print');
      elem.classList.add('hide-print');
    }
  });  
}

onPrintEvents(btns, 'show-print', 'hide-print');
exitPrintEvents('show-print', 'hide-print');
```

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  border: 5px solid blue;
  gap: 10px;
}

.child {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.purple-bg {
  background-color: purple;
}

.red-bg {
  background-color: red;
}

.deeppink-bg {
  background-color: deeppink;
}

.lightsalmon-bg {
  background-color: lightsalmon;
}

@media print {
  body {
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
    print-color-adjust: exact;
  }
  
  .hide-print {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Print Clicked Button Element ONLY</h1>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <button class="purple-bg">Button 1</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="child">
    <button class="red-bg">Button 2</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="child">
    <button class="deeppink-bg">Button 3</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="child">
    <button class="lightsalmon-bg">Button 4</button>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another workable way I found using Javascript is to, basically, temporary set the CSS display attribute for elements with the class "no-print" to none. Then call window.print(). It prints without those elements. After that, reset the original display attributes to each.

e.g., on clicking a "print' button,

```
printButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const noPrint = [...document.getElementsByClassName("no-print")];
    const property = [];
    noPrint.forEach((item) => {
        property.push(item.style.getPropertyValue("display"));
        item.style.setProperty("display", "none");
    });
    window.print();
    noPrint.forEach((item) => {
        item.style.setProperty("display", property.shift());
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Set the style of the element you want to print to position:fixed,then make it cover the whole page.

Comment: Unreliable as content "behind" might "spill" from the bottom if it's taller than what you actually want to print or worse, cause a repeated content page printing

Answer (score -7):

Here is another (perhaps a more modern?) solution:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="print.css">
```

Comment: This isn't really an answer - it provides nothing other than a linked style sheet.  Please give us the rest of the answer.