# Print in the background with javascript i.e. without document pop up

Tags: javascript, printing, window

Found this code to print from javascript.  But it opens a window with the document to be printed.  Is there a way to hide that document?

```
var element=document.getElementById(element_id);
var newWin=window.open('','Print-Window','width=400,height=400,top=100,left=100');

newWin.document.open();
/* newWin.document.title = "Readings on PageLinks"; */
newWin.document.write('<html><head><title>Readings on PageLinks</title></head><body   onload="window.print()">'+element.innerHTML+'</body></html>');
newWin.document.close();

setTimeout(function(){ newWin.close(); },10);
```

The print is done onload() for that document, so I guess printing could not be done without it.  But can it be hidden?

Comment: You're looking for the ability to print a section of a document, not print without the OS Print dialog, right?

Comment: I am looking for a way to hide the `newWin.document` created above.  Is there a method that does that?

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using a print-specific stylesheet as described in [How to print only a selected HTML element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500962/how-to-print-only-a-selected-html-element) Don't use `window.open()` at all; use CSS classes (dynamically applied if need be) to specify which elements should/shouldn't be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your markup:

```
<iframe id="ifrOutput" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

Add the following javascript function:

```
function printContainer(content, styleSheet) {
    var output = document.getElementById("ifrOutput").contentWindow;
    output.document.open();
    if (styleSheet !== undefined) {
        output.document.write('<link href="' + styleSheet + '" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
    }
    output.document.write(content);
    output.document.close();
    output.focus();
    output.print();
}
```

And call it like so:

```
// with stylesheet
printHtml('<div>Styled markup</div>', 'printStyles.css');

// without stylesheet
printHtml('<div>Unstyled markup</div>');
```