# Window.print() doing nothing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a small chrome extension to help my grandpa print images easily through a button in the context menu. I got to the point that the image opens on a seperate tab, after debugging I found out that "window.print()" got triggered but nothing happend.

My background.js file:

```
var printEnable = false;

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "title": "Print",
    "type": "normal",
    "contexts": ["image"],
    "onclick": function(info) {
        chrome.tabs.create({url: info.srcUrl});
        this.printEnable = true;
    }
});

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(){
    if(printEnable){
        window.print();
        this.printEnable = false;
    }
});
```

My manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Print",
  "description": "Easy picture print",
  "permissions": [ "contextMenus","tabs"],
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },  
  "icons": { "16": "calculator-16.png", "128": "calculator-128.png" }
}
```

Can someone please help me find whats wrong with my code?

Comment: It seems the second method is not invoking.chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener

Comment: You are not passing anything to the callback function in the `background.js`? You are referencing the backgrounds window instead of the required one when you are calling `window.print();`. Nevertheless invoking the print dialog from a popup or a background page is impossible.

Comment: Xan gave a simple example regarding this problem in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24193885/6586663) answer. I do believe tho that it can be done much simpler from a content script. Perhaps try using a function from my answer regarding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47728358/6586663) question to select and print the required image.