# How to print a chart using IceFaces/JSF

Tags: jsf, icefaces-3

How can I make use of  `downloadAsImage()` to download/print the chart in PNG format?

I used `exportToChart()` as mentioned below but it just displays the chart under the existing chart.

```
<h:form id="exportForm">
    <h:commandButton id="exportButton" value="Export as Image"
                     onclick="exportChart.exportToImage(ice.ace.jq('.chartExport')); 
                              return false;" />
<ace:chart ...
               widgetVar="exportChart" />
</h:form>
<h:graphicImage styleClass="chartExport" />
```

**Edit**
Tried this:

```
<ice:commandButton  value="Print" 
        onclick="$('barChart').printElement();" >
        <ace:printer for="barChart"></ace:printer>
</ice:commandButton>
```

where **`barChart`** is id for the chart.  This only prints the legend and numeric values but not actual graph.

Comment: By 'printing' it... via a print button... Or check if IceFaces has a 'print' component (PrimeFaces has)

Comment: I don't wanna use a print button or just do "Cntrl+P". I want a dedicated button to export/download/print the chart. And yes, I tried with <ace:printer> but it just prints numerics, not the whole image.

Comment: If you exported the image first  I'd expect `ace:printer` to print the image as well. And you cannot directly print from a webpage without having the print window popping up. Tried `window.print()` in the onlclick after the export (or whatever the javascript function for 'print' is....

Comment: I'm unable to export it. When I use exportToImage(), it displays the image right under the graph/chart with same dimensions. And yes, I do agree about the print window popping up. I just want to print a particular chart from a page with 2-3 charts/graphs. (separate print button for each chart/graph)

Comment: Well, that is displays it right below the original chart is because that is what your (x)html does... Try using the solution in the 12 upvoted answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500962/how-to-print-only-a-selected-html-element

Comment: In PrimeFaces (on which these ace components are based) I can print the **exported** image with the `p:printer` (targetting the id of the image tag where the exported image is ending up on. I can also use the javascript that is on the button of the printer after the export in the same javascript. So the same might work for icefaces

Comment: I've added what I've tried in the question.

Comment: Shouldn't `onclick="$('barChart').printElement();"` be an export? Now you twice print it.

Comment: I meant to say I used this:  onclick="exportChart.exportToImage(ice.ace.jq('.chartExport'));" and this: " onclick="$('barChart').printElement();"  on two different buttons to see which one works. First one just displays image under the chart and second one prints legend and numeric but not the whole graph.

Comment: Combine Them....