# Laravel Print retrieved data

Tags: laravel, printing

I retrieved data from two tables and view them successfully.I want to print them.print button also in the same form.Then how to call print function with these retrieved data.

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6500966/4575350

Comment: Not clear to me what you want

Comment: I searched that.If I can transfer data from page to another blade I am OK.but still not a clue.. thanks

Comment: I retrieved data and view the in a table.Simply now I want to print them using a PRINT button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print your view you can add this to your view:

```
 <button onclick="display()">Click to Print</button>
  <script>
     function display() {
        window.print();
     }
  </script>
```