# Print a single component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hey guys I've tried to create a print button that prints a single component when clicked,when using :

```
  const onPrint = () => {
    window.print();
  };
```

yet what's being printed is the entire page.

I have a list of components that contain an image mainly and i want the image to be printed when clicking the button.

Is this possible to do?

[image: and it looks like this]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500962/how-to-print-only-a-selected-html-element

Comment: It still prints the entire list

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135387/how-to-print-react-component-on-click-of-a-button

Comment: thanks a lot , i used this library from the answer your gave : https://github.com/gregnb/react-to-print