# Adding close.window

Tags: javascript, printing

Maybe I'm stupid, but I can't seem to post in a thread:)

My question is about the below thread:
[Print <div id=printarea></div> only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468881/print-div-id-printarea-div-only/1019785#1019785)

This option of Sandro's and Westy's combo works perfectly for me except for I would like the window to close on completion.
Any Ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use `window.close ()`?

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks for your reply. My knowledge of javascript is poor. Where should I place it in the code?

Comment: Uh, where you want to close the window?  I'm not 100% sure without seeing your code

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I'm using

```
<head>

<script language="javascript">

var gAutoPrint = true;

function processPrint(printMe){

if (document.getElementById != null){

var html = '<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n';

if (document.getElementsByTagName != null){

var headTags = document.getElementsByTagName("head");

if (headTags.length > 0) html += headTags[0].innerHTML;

}

html += '\n</HE' + 'AD>\n<BODY>\n';

var printReadyElem = document.getElementById(printMe);

if (printReadyElem != null) html += printReadyElem.innerHTML;

else{

alert("Error, no contents.");

return;

}

html += '\n</BO' + 'DY>\n</HT' + 'ML>';

var printWin = window.open("","processPrint");

printWin.document.open();

printWin.document.write(html);

printWin.document.close();

if (gAutoPrint) printWin.print();
        Response.Write("window.close()");

} else alert("Browser not supported.");

}

</script>

</head>

<body>

<a class="button" href="javascript:void(processPrint('address'));">Print Address</a>

</body>
```

Thanks :-)