# javascript:window.print() not working with fancybox

Tags: javascript, printing, fancybox

I have an html page (let's call parent) with a link that opens another html page (call this child) in fancybox. 
Inside the child html, I have this anchor

```
<a href="javascript:window.print();" style="color:#663300;">Imprimir</a><br />
```

The problem is, this prints the the **parent AND the child** page. Is this the typical fancybox behaviour? How do I print **only the child**?

Comment: the div u want to print is #fancybox-content

check out this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468881/print-div-id-printarea-div-only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edit from code on other threads... this should work

```
<style type="text/css">
    @media print
    {
        body * { visibility: hidden; }
        #fancybox-content * { visibility: visible; }
        #fancybox-content { position: absolute; top: 1px; left: 1px; }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: thanks, I used this css:
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
 body * { visibility: hidden; }
 #fancybox-content * { visibility: visible; }
 #fancybox-content { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }
 body, html, div, #fancybox-content { background: #FFF !important; }

Answer (score 0):

yes.  The js command you're calling is window.print().  What you need to do is only print the container of the fancybox.   A quick google search came up with a bunch of links on how to do this.  Here's one:

[Print <div id=printarea></div> only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468881/print-div-id-printarea-div-only)