# Jquery printing colorbox window

Tags: jquery, printing, popup, window, colorbox

I am trying to print just the contents of a colorbox

```
$(".print-invoice").on("click", function(event){
    window.print();
  return false;
});
```

This prints the whole page, the file path is popups/info.html

Comment: Possible duplicate [Print <div id=printarea></div> only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468881/print-div-id-printarea-div-only)

Comment: @N0nh4x0rツ not sure how you thought the div printing and colorbox printing are possible duplicates?!!

Comment: @Walahh what are the differences??!!, from my limited knowledge, I think `colorbox` is build with `div`s and/or `span`s??!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$(".print-invoice").click(function() {
    $('#the_Iframe_ID')[0].print();
});
```

Comment: $('#myid')[0].print(); //console - is not a function

Comment: Try: $("#the_Iframe_ID").get(0).contentWindow.print();

Answer (score 0):

Its a few months late, but for the benefit of anyone else who may come across this:
If you use an iframe to display the content, then a print button in that content will only print whats in the colorbox. To use an iframe, set the `iframe` setting to true:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".linktocolorbox").colorbox({iframe:true});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution on inner HTML with multiple divs with same class

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32580793/3888517