# Print a Div issue in IE with Jquery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to a print a div using the Jquery plugin.

I'm using this plugin:

```
jQuery.print.js
```

But it is not working in IE.

Please let me know if there are any good jQuery plugins which will work for Chrome and Safari and other Browsers.

I don't want to use JavaScript. I'm looking for Plugins.

I have tried searching for Plugins in Google and did not get help from it.

I've tried using `jquery.PrintArea.js` plugin but in IE getting following message:

```
JavaScript runtime error: Out of memory
```

**EDIT:**
Is there a jQuery plugin to print a part of the div for Opera, Safari and Chrome Browsers.

Comment: Regarding your sentence `I don't want to use JavaScript`: jQuery is JavaScript!

Comment: I don't know any jQuery plugins for this use case, but you can checkout an answer from me (written 1 year ago): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12181760/twitter-bootstrap-print-content-of-modal-window/12181825#12181825