# Print button to print a a table from database

Tags: php, database, printing, row

I want to know how to print following table from my database. This is its form when showed on the browser.

I want to print this table, and I'm confused because I made a print button, but when I press it, it prints the whole webpage.

How can I print only the table?

```
DATE:   ||AMOUNT:

2013   || 2000

2013   || 200

2013   || 2000

2013   || 2000

TOTAL AMOUNT PAID:  6200

TOTAL TUITION:    9000

REMAINING BALANCE:  2800
```

Comment: create a blank page with only the table in it, nothing else..

Comment: there's no other way? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="printableArea">
      // wrap your content within this div
      DATE:   ||AMOUNT:

      2013   || 2000

      2013   || 200

      2013   || 2000

      2013   || 2000

      TOTAL AMOUNT PAID:  6200

      TOTAL TUITION:    9000

      REMAINING BALANCE:  2800
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="printDiv('printableArea')" value="Print" />
```

And the button click javascript

```
function printDiv(divName) {
     var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
     var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

     document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

     window.print();

     document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```

Source : [One of SO Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468881/print-div-id-printarea-div-only/7532581#7532581)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to as tradyblix said in their comment, create a page with just the table on it. You can have a button that takes you to that page.

In that page, you can have javascript automatically print it.. 
To do that in the head put this in

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function print_page() {
  window.print();
}
</script>
```

And on the body tag

```
<body onload="print_page()">
```

Comment: yes i used this code once, but it'll be time consuming if i use another page to print a table.. thnx anyways.. :D XOXO

Comment: LOL. this onee print whole page. not answering the question. plus the questioner also lol