# How to print HTML content on click of a button, but not the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I want to print some HTML content, when the user clicks on a button. Once the user clicks on that button, the print dialog of the browser will open, but it will not print the webpage. Instead, it will print the some other HTML content which is not displayed on the page.

While asking this question, there are few solutions coming into my mind. But I am not sure whether those are good ideas or something better can be done. One of those solutions are:
I can keep this HTML content in a div and make it `display:` to print, but `display: none` to screen. All other elements on the webpage can be made to `display: none` for print and `display:` for the screen. And then call to print.

Any better idea?

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: (Further considering that the highest rated answer here is using code from [one of the answers to the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7532581/254830) almost verbatim)

Comment: this library can help with printing selected html elements in a page: http://printjs.crabbly.com/

Answer (score 218):

```css
@media print {
  .noPrint{
    display:none;
  }
}
h1{
  color:#f6f6;
}
```

```html
<h1>
print me
</h1>
<h1 class="noPrint">
no print
</h1>
<button onclick="window.print();" class="noPrint">
Print Me
</button>
```

I came across another elegant solution for this:

Place your printable part inside a div with an id like this:

```
<div id="printableArea">
      <h1>Print me</h1>
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="printDiv('printableArea')" value="print a div!" />
```

Now let's create a really simple javascript:

```
function printDiv(divName) {
     var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
     var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

     document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

     window.print();

     document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```

SOURCE : [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7532581/1223045)

Comment: What will this do to the event listeners?

Comment: How to open that in new window?

Comment: using same solution but this only prints innerHTML not the styles of page even border of table disappears......................... function Printable(div_id)
{
var DocumentContainer = document.getElementById(div_id);
  WindowObject.document.writeln(DocumentContainer.innerHTML;);
    WindowObject.document.close();
    WindowObject.focus();
    WindowObject.print();
}   This is the code for opening it in new window.

Comment: this may destroy your animations and events that was added by js after load. Use with caution.

Comment: To get the styles involved, you just need to use the `<link>` for the style-sheet inside the div

Comment: This seems overly convoluted. 
@media print is a much cleaner solution (see 2ne's post below).

Comment: My dom event handlers are gone after reattaching the original content.

Comment: Not working for me :(

Comment: This will affect the original page after printing.

Comment: Worked for me. Asp.net webform 4.6.2 call function from a button.

Comment: @nimeresam I am using this solution and after printing the popup i am not able to close the popup. Do you have any alternative solution for this?

Answer (score 127):

Here is a pure css version

```css
.example-print {
    display: none;
}
@media print {
   .example-screen {
       display: none;
    }
    .example-print {
       display: block;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="example-screen">You only see me in the browser</div>

<div class="example-print">You only see me in the print</div>
```

Comment: I like that you don't need to open a new window and all that crap.

Comment: @Robusto agree in one hand, but I don't like how it's not so good for saving the page (without needing to print), not to mention when there's paging to be handled. preparing a page to "print" is ambiguous in that sense.

Answer (score 86):

According to [this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468881/print-div-id-printarea-div-only) you can print a specific div with

```
w=window.open();
w.document.write(document.getElementsByClassName('report_left_inner')[0].innerH‌​TML);
w.print();
w.close();
```

Comment: This solution requires JQuery which is not mentioned (or tagged) in the question. You should specify this dependency in your answer.

Comment: replacing `$('.report_left_inner').html()` by vanilla js would make this the best answer on the page for simplicity and robustness

Comment: `w.document.write(document.getElementsByClassName('report_left_inner')[0].innerHTML);`

Comment: This is excellent. One point of caution though: you'll need to check and inject your style rules separately, or it'll fall back to bare HTML. For that I personally did `document.write('<style>'+ ... + '</style>');` before the `document.write()` given here.

Comment: This is interesting but when I tried it from an Angular component I didn't get the CSS applied to the new window.  Also, the images don't have time to load between the write call and the print call so they don't appear until after the print dialog is done.

Comment: This is not working in current versions of chrome, also, popups may be blocked by the users browser.

Comment: This creates a visible tab in the browser under the print dialog, which is pretty ugly.

Answer (score 11):

**I Want See This**

Example http://jsfiddle.net/35vAN/

```
    <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.1.min.js" > </script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

    function PrintElem(elem)
    {
        Popup($(elem).html());
    }

    function Popup(data) 
    {
        var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=400,width=600');
        mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>my div</title>');
        /*optional stylesheet*/ //mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />');
        mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        mywindow.document.write(data);
        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

        mywindow.print();
        mywindow.close();

        return true;
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mydiv">
    This will be printed. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque a quam at nibh adipiscing interdum. Nulla vitae accumsan ante. 
</div>

<div>
    This will not be printed.
</div>

<div id="anotherdiv">
    Nor will this.
</div>

<input type="button" value="Print Div" onclick="PrintElem('#mydiv')" />

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not working in IE 11

Answer (score 10):

Below Code May Be Help You :

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function printPage(id)
{
   var html="<html>";
   html+= document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;

   html+="</html>";

   var printWin = window.open('','','left=0,top=0,width=1,height=1,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status  =0');
   printWin.document.write(html);
   printWin.document.close();
   printWin.focus();
   printWin.print();
   printWin.close();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="block1">
<table border="1" >
</tr>
<th colspan="3">Block 1</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>1</th><th>XYZ</th><th>athock</th>
</tr>
</table>

</div>

<div id="block2">
    This is Block 2 content
</div>

<input type="button" value="Print Block 1" onclick="printPage('block1');"></input>
<input type="button" value="Print Block 2" onclick="printPage('block2');"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow! This is the most straightforward answer I ever saw in Stackoverflow yet.

Answer (score 2):

If you add and remove the innerHTML, all javascript, css and more will be loaded twice, and the events will fire twice (happened to me), is better hide content, using jQuery and css like this:

```
function printDiv(selector) {
    $('body .site-container').css({display:'none'});
    var content = $(selector).clone();
    $('body .site-container').before(content);
    window.print();
    $(selector).first().remove();
    $('body .site-container').css({display:''});
}
```

The div "site-container" contain all site, so you can call the function like:

```
printDiv('.someDiv');
```

Comment: Hi Alejo. Clever solution, but it doesn't work in IE. Could you please help me with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49410902 THaNKS!