# How to print a search result in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using PHP and CodeIgniter. I have a page that containing the data from database and \ search option in that screen. I'm designing the new page for print the same data. How can I link the new page for print? For example:

View page:

[image]

I want to print the display result in another new page, like:

[image]

How to get the result from screen 1 to screen 2?

Comment: I really don't understand what you want, clarify with some code please?

Comment: could you able to understand, i have a list view page with the search option.. i want to print the search result in another page..

Comment: Still vague, are you trying to add every search result in a new page, or do you just want all the data from the database in another view without an searchfield?

Comment: actually i want to print the result in new page whether only if click the printer icon in top of the table.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to add a search result to another page when you click on the printer icon at the top of the table?

Comment: Well, what you could do is when you click on the printerbutton the printer is sending the ID from the result you want to print to another controller and in that controller get the results again based on the ID and then show this result in another view.

Comment: here is your reply http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16894683/how-to-print-html-content-on-click-of-a-button-but-not-the-page

Comment: Thank u so much for your reply. I'm searching many fields like date, name, id.... So, i must send the all the details whatever i'm search and get the result again.. if i understand correctly...

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to redesign (alter) the presentation when you are printing that page/content and in this case (if really this is the case) you may add a different `css styles` for `print media`, for example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css">
```

if you add another CSS file and style those elements differently in that CSS file then those styles would be applied only when the pages is being printed, so you may add in that CSS:

```
#search_bar_at_top {
    display:none; /*Hide the search bar*/
}
```

Or using in the same CSS file using `media print`:

```
@media print{
    #search_bar_at_top {
        display:none; /*Hide the search bar*/
    }
}
```

Check more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) and other helpful articles:

1. [How To Set Up A Print Style Sheet](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/)
2. [Print Different](http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200001.html)
3. [CSS Media Types Create Print-Friendly Pages](http://webdesign.about.com/cs/css/a/aa042103a.htm)