# How to print HTML content in angular8 project?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to print just the chart but when I click to the button it prints to all of the window (with buttons and icons)

[image: you will find a screenshot here]

the code is
***app.component.ts***

```
  OnPrint() {

    window.print();
  }
```

***styles.css***

```css
    @media print {
    
      body * {
    
        visibility: visible;
    
      }
    
      #section-to-print, #section-to-print * {
    
        visibility: visible;
    
      }
      :host {
        display: none;
      }
    
      #section-to-print {
    
        position: absolute;
    
        left: 0;
    
        top: 10px;
        width: 230px;
        height: 330px;
    
      }
    
    }
    
    body{
      margin: 10px;
    }
    
    *{
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print HTML content on click of a button, but not the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16894683/how-to-print-html-content-on-click-of-a-button-but-not-the-page)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
@media print {

 .section-to-hide-in-print {
    visibility: hidden;
 }

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Wrap the section you want to print in a div, and send the divs id to the function.

```
<div id="sectionToPrint">
      ////
</div>

<input type="button" (click)="onPrint('sectionToPrint')" value="print a div!" />
```

Then add an event like an onclick (as shown above), and pass the id of the div like above.

Now create a really simple javascript:

```
onPrint(divName) {
     const printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
     const originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
     document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
     window.print();
     document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```

SOURCE : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7532581/1223045
There are other ways to achieve what you are trying to do, but I feel this is the easiest way.

Comment: @chaabaninejma changed it to typescript. hope this is helpful.

Comment: @chaabaninejma please mark this answer as correct if it is what you're looking for :)

Comment: @chaabaninejma code is messy. after print, the page becomes unusable. you cannot click anywhere. If you click cancel print, page become unusable as well

Comment: I'd imagine that's because ripping out the html that angular is running on and bound to and then plopping it back in probably breaks Angular's "brain"