# How can I insert a Print button that prints a form in a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, forms, printing

So, lets say I got a simple form inside a page like this:

```
<form style="text-align:center;">
    <p> STUFF </p>
</form>
```

I wanna add a button so when the user clicks on it the browser's Print dialog shows up, how can I do that?

Edit: I wanna print the form, not the page.

Comment: Do you want to print just the form, or the entire page?

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that, i want to print the form.

Comment: This has nothing to do with asp.net mvc.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

**Print the whole page**

Try adding a button that calls [`window.print()`](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/newtech2.shtml)

```
<input type="button" value="Print this page" onClick="window.print()">
```

**Print a specific portion/container in a page**

```
<div id="print-content">
 <form>

  <input type="button" onclick="printDiv('print-content')" value="print a div!"/>
</form>
</div>
```

then in the HTML file, add this script code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function printDiv(divName) {
        var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
        w=window.open();
        w.document.write(printContents);
        w.print();
        w.close();
    }
</script>
```

Refer [Print <div id="printarea"></div> only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468881/print-div-id-printarea-div-only)

Comment: where im supposed to place the function ?

Comment: thanks but it does nothing when ever i click the button, any idea ?

Comment: Ya thanks it worked before the last update, just more couple questions, can i hide the header and footer (page number and date)? and the text align keep changes to left by itself, any idea ?

Comment: find it in DOM and hide using their ids. like `document.getElementById('footer).style.display=none` then call print

Comment: well i couldnt do that but thanks anyway, at least its printing

Comment: Great answer. Just what I was looking for. Here's a working codepen http://codepen.io/martinkrulltott/pen/vObppZ

Comment: Hi, Do we have any way to verify, whether the content has loaded completely in that DIV ?

Comment: @NandaKishoreAllu you could validate if it has any child elements like `if ($("#urdivId").html().length > 0) or .text().length`

Comment: CTRL + F5 - mine wouldn't work either and kept saying the call to js wasn't there until I did that.

Answer (score 3):

To print with submit button, add this to your summit script:

`<input type="button" value="Print this page" onClick="window.print()">`

Keep in mind, this will only trigger whatever browser implemented [print](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print) capabilities are available at the client.

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) there are to lift your quality content up

Comment: TS want to print the form. not the page.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the `window.print()`:

```
<form style="text-align:center;">

  <p> STUFF </p>

  <a href="#" id="lnkPrint">Print</a>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#lnkPrint').click(function()
     {
         window.print();
     });
});
```

Comment: i created a javascript and placed the code and added the <a..></a> but nothing happens when i click it

Comment: This is using jQuery. Have you included jQuery?

Comment: I have put together a jsFiddle to show it working. Notice how it is including jQuery 1.8.3: http://jsfiddle.net/LP8VJ/

Comment: Nope sorry, im pretty new how can i do that ?

Comment: There are no jquery tags on this page. So a jquery solution is, IMO, invalid. Not to mention this is trivial to do without including a third party package.

Answer (score 0):

As well as the above there are a couple of other approches you can take here:

```html
<a href="Javascript:window.print();">Print</a>
```

and to not include any JS in your HTML:

```js
const el = document.getElementById("aTag");
el.addEventListener("click", () => { window.print();});
```

```html
<a id="aTag">print</a>
```