# Insert a Print Button for A website Form

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add a print button for a form on the website that I maintain for a voluntary organization in Scotland. I would stress that I am not an expert in either HTML or Javascript but do my best.

The answer given by [Murali](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1559213/murali) to question [20101409](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101409/how-can-i-insert-a-print-button-that-prints-a-form-in-a-webpage) on 20th November 2013 looks as if it should work but does not. I suspect that I not named or defined something correctly.

My test webpage is: http://clanmacthomas.co.uk/Pages/TestCalculations.aspx

Comment: the "printDiv" function is undefined and the area where it looks like you're trying to define it is a mess.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly discourage the use `<a href="javascript:..something..">` for any purpose, and especially the use of links to perform actions, preferring buttons instead.

If you have

```
<div>stuff</div>
<div>more stuff</div>
<input type="button" id="print" value="Print this page">
```

You can later attach a handler to it by using

```
<script>
document.getElementById("print").addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (window.print) window.print();
});
</script>
```

If you are likely to want a print button on more than that one page, put that code in a `.js` file

```
/* printer.js */
document.getElementById("print").addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (window.print) window.print();
});
```

There are nicer ways to do it if you are using *jQuery*, but you didn't mention that so I'm avoiding it.

You may want to read the SO question "[Correct usage of addEventListener() / attachEvent()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2657182/17300)" since older versions of Internet Explorer use attachEvent instead of addEventListener.

Answer (score 0):

To add a link that will open the print dialog on a webpage, include this link somewhere:

```
<a href="javascript:if(window.print)window.print()">Print</a>
```

Comment: please don't encourage inline scripting. your answer is valid, but highly abused by n00bs. and i don't want to sound discouraging, rather, encouraging. its a good answer