# Print the HTML form with User Filled Information/Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, dynamic-values

I have HTML form and I would like to print the HTML form, with the User Filled Information/Content.

Is there exist any way in jQuery or JavaScript to get a HTML Form with user filled values and print it?

This is what I have tried

`$(form).html()` but it returns only empty form
`$(document).find("form").html()` which also returned html with empty form.

NOTE: I am not talking about serialize function here. I don't want to submit a form but want to convert form to a printable version by setting input, select background transparent.

Comment: Can you reword your question? And show us what you have tried?

Comment: are you talking about serializing data?

Comment: Very likely, but you can provide 1) the specific code you're using, and 2) what you want to do with that information once you have it?

Comment: Sounds like you just want to serialize the form. If you are looking at getting all the inputs from your form, you can do this individually by `$('.class-name').val()`. But yeah, like others are saying, more code is needed to solve your question.

Comment: ok, guys, edited question again for more clearence.

Comment: Why not just rebuild the form with the values on a printable page and disable all form elements?

Comment: that is long work, there must exist a short way, I am about to complete this just in 3-5 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$('form').find('input').each(function( key, value ) {
    console.log(value);
});
```

And to get the data ready for **POST** or something like it use this

```
$('form').serialize();
```

Comment: I have explained in NOTE, Its not serialize case :)

Comment: @Wasim then try the first solution with the each function!

Comment: @Wasim can you post a fiddle for your problem? it will be much easier to help

Answer (score 0):

I think I got your issue. What you are actually want is, to print the HTML form, but it should contain the User Input.

First and foremost, you can use the 'window.print()' method. If you want to print only the Form, then you should use some CSS tricks.

I guess, what you are looking is answered in the following SO Questions. Please check out.

1. [Javascript print web form with user input included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29834546/javascript-print-web-form-with-user-input-included)
2. [How to print only a selected HTML element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500962/how-to-print-only-a-selected-html-element)

If you are still not able to get your solution done, then let me know. Let me see how I can help you. Good Luck.

Comment: Have a look at this jQuery Plugin - http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/

And this blog post about using the plugin - http://www.codediesel.com/browser/printing-selective-dom-elements-on-a-page/