# what can i put into myservlet to show database elements in .jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Hi how can I show the elements in my .jsp when I add something to my database.
Here is my empservlet or the servlet of my code

```
    //empServlet
  package emppackage;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;



public class empServlet extends HttpServlet {

String forward;
//empDAO myempDAO;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
//private empDAO disempdao;

public empServlet() {
    super();

  // myempDAO= new empDAO();
}



protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


}


protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    empServices empserv= new empServices();


    empserv.empadd(request.getParameter("eFname"),request.getParameter("eLname"),request.getParameter("eNameRes"),request.getParameter("eSerials"),request.getParameter("eJrss"),request.getParameter("eBand"),request.getParameter("eAcct"),request.getParameter("ePMPs"),request.getParameter("esJRSS"),request.getParameter("eOpenSeatDesc"),request.getParameter("eReqSkills"),request.getParameter("eReqBand"),request.getParameter("eDreject"),request.getParameter("eRreject"),request.getParameter("eDetActPlan"),request.getParameter("eDataComplete"),request.getParameter("eStat"));

    //doGet(request, response);
}

}
```

Here is my employee dao where it is at arraylist

```
         //empDAO
     public List<empGetSet> getAllEmp()
 {

List<empGetSet> empdetails = new ArrayList<empGetSet>();

try {

    Connection conn = getConnection();
    String showsql = "SELECT *FROM csemp;";
    PreparedStatement psread= conn.prepareStatement(showsql);
    ResultSet rsread = psread.executeQuery();

    while (rsread.next()) 
    {

        empGetSet readgetset = new empGetSet();

        readgetset.setFname(rsread.getString(1));
        readgetset.setLname(rsread.getString(2));
        readgetset.setNameRes(rsread.getString(3));
        readgetset.setSerials(rsread.getString(4));
        readgetset.setJrss(rsread.getString(5));
        readgetset.setBand(rsread.getString(6));
        readgetset.setAcct(rsread.getString(7));
        readgetset.setPMPs(rsread.getString(8));
        readgetset.setsJRSS(rsread.getString(9));
        readgetset.setOpenSeatDesc(rsread.getString(10));
        readgetset.setReqSkills(rsread.getString(11));
        readgetset.setReqBand(rsread.getString(12));
        readgetset.setDreject(rsread.getString(13));
        readgetset.setsRreject(rsread.getString(14));
        readgetset.setDetActPlan(rsread.getString(15));
        readgetset.setDataComplete(rsread.getString(16));
        readgetset.setStat(rsread.getString(17));


        empdetails.add(readgetset);
        psread.close();
        conn.close();
    }


}
```

Here is my created jsp

```
 <%@ page language="java" 
   contentType="text/html; 
  charset=ISO-8859-1"
  pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"
   import = "thisPackage.GetSet"
    import = "thisPackage.LoginServlet"
    import = "thisPackage.LogoutServlet"
     %>

   <%
     response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache,         must-revalidate");
   response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");

    %>


 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
   <title>Hi welcome</title>
    </head>
   <body>


<center>

    <h3>Hello </h3> 

</center>

   <form action ="LogoutServlet" method="post">

   <div align="right"><input type = "submit"  value= "Logout"></div>

 </form>

  <table border =1 cellpadding="18">
 <thead>
<tr>
         <th>     First Name</th>
         <th>      Last Name</th>
        <th>      Name of Resource (LN ID Format)</th>
        <th>      Serial Number</th>
        <th>     JRSS</th>
         <th>     Band</th>
         <th>    Account (Proposed)</th>
        <th>    PMP Seat</th>
        <th>    Seat JRSS</th>
        <th>    Open Seat Description</th>
        <th>     Required Skills</th>
        <th>    Required Band low/high</th>
        <th>    Date of Rejection</th>
        <th>Reason for Rejection</th>
        <th>Detailed Action Plan</th>
        <th>Target Date of Completion</th>
        <th>Status(Ongoing/Closed)</th>
        <th colspan=2>Do This</th>

   </tr>
  </thead>


   </table>
  <a href ="addDetails.jsp">Add Details</a>
 </body>
</html>
```

How can I make it show, I've found some resources but I cant somehow put that into my project because it would not fit the way I write my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your servlet, you can set the request attribute to your DAO query result object. And then loop through the same to print the data grid in your jsp page.

**Servlet Code >>**

```
protected void listEmployees(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    List<empGetSet> empdetails = employeeDAO.getAllEmp(); //or call employeeService layer which calls employeDAO
    request.setAttribute("empdetails", empdetails);
    //dispatcher forward code
}
```

**JSP Code >>**

```
<c:forEach var="emp" items="${empdetails}">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${emp.id}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${emp.firstName}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${emp.lastName}" /></td>
        <!--- etc etc data -->      
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

**NOTE:** Please correct your DAO, you are closing `PreparedStatement` & `Connection` inside the while loop of resultset read. Take it out of while loop of `rsread.next()`. If you are using Java 1.7 and above, I always recommend to use [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), much cleaner & safer code.

**UPDATE:**

You have two options for JSP action mapping:

1. Using Link

   ```
   <a href="/list">Show List</a> <!-- this will call doGet() method -->
   ```
2. Using Form

   ```
   <form action="list" method="post">
           <input type="submit" value="Show List" /> <!-- this will call doPost() method -->
      </form>
   ```

You have two options at servlet side url mapping:

1. Annotation (on Servlet class)

   `@WebServlet("/employees")
   public class EmpServlet extends HttpServlet {
    /* code */
   }`
2. Configuration (in web.xml)

   `<servlet>
       <servlet-name>EmpServlet</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>com.test.EmpServlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>EmpServlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/employees</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>`

And finally your servlet code will look like this:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(request, response); //if form action chosen
}

// if using doGet() / href option
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String action = request.getServletPath();

        //you can implement switch case here if having more possible actions/links on the page
        if(action.equals("/list")){
            List<empGetSet> empdetails = employeeDAO.getAllEmp(); //or call employeeService layer which calls employeDAO
            request.setAttribute("empdetails", empdetails);
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("Employees.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }
}
```

Comment: thanks man, I've encountered this when I wrote <c:forEach items="${empdet}" var ="${empdetails}"> ------> "var" does not support runtime expressions. I have already added this tag   <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" prefix="c"%>

Comment: Try JSTL1.1 taglib `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %> `

Comment: how can i print the display when I click a button

Comment: I am guessing you are talking about printer print at client side, which directs that you have to use javascript for that. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101409/how-can-i-insert-a-print-button-that-prints-a-form-in-a-webpage) will assist you.

Comment: i mean when I click a button named "Show List" it will display the contents of each column from the database to the .jsp form