# Print a div in Chrome and Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery

**jQuery**

```
 $(function(){
    $("#btnPrint").click(function(){
      var mydiv = document.getElementById("printDiv");
    printDiv(mydiv);
    });

    });

    function printDiv(divP) {

                window.frames["print_frame"].document.body.innerHTML = $(divP).html();
                window.frames["print_frame"].window.focus();
                window.frames["print_frame"].window.print();

            }
```

**HTML**

```
 <iframe name="print_frame" width="0" height="0" frameborder="0" src="about:blank">
        </iframe>

<div id="printDiv">
//some content here
</div>

<input type="button" id="btnPrint" value="Print"/>
```

The above code is working in IE and Mozilla but not working in Safari,chome and Opera? Please help..

Comment: It works fine for me (chrome  31.0.1650.63) maybe you have some other JS error on page?

Comment: "Not working" means what exactly? What does it do and what is it supposed to do? Are there errors in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners)?

Comment: No errors. it is printing white page.

Comment: Check your chrome version. Its working fine for mi. Chrome version  31.0.1650.63

Comment: works for me with latest chrome http://jsfiddle.net/Nu5SX/

Comment: heres a better way to print a single div http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468881/print-div-id-printarea-div-only

Answer (score 6):

It looks like the purpose of this demo is to print only a single div, is that correct?

If so, it is [easiest to use media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468881/print-div-id-printarea-div-only) for a cross browser solution

http://jsfiddle.net/Nu5SX/2/

```
@media print {
    body * {
       visibility: hidden;
    }
    #printDiv, #printDiv * {
       visibility: visible;
    }
    #printDiv {
       position: absolute;
       left: 0;
       top: 0;
    }
}
```

simple javascript

```
    window.print();
```

EDIT: sorry for talking like clippy :)

Comment: Thanks but I want to hide the printDiv by default. just checkout: http://jsfiddle.net/Nu5SX/3/

Comment: I used a modified version to print a specific part of page online. Thanks for your inspiration!