# Print only jQuery UI Dialog Content

Tags: printing, dialog

I have a modal form, which opens on click of button. it contains text I want to print.

I have hidden every other elements in print.css except the div which contains my print data.
when I press ctrl + p it shows only the data I wanna print, just as I wanted it to be, but it does not fit the printing A4 page. text is positioned in left top corner of paper and part of it (right side) is hidden.

I tried every possible style in print.css to make the content fit printable area, but nothing changes :( could anyone please help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print <div id="printarea"></div> only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468881/print-div-id-printarea-div-only)

Answer (score 0):

Use something like:

```
@media screen {
    .printable { display: none; }
    .non-printable { display: block; }
}
@media print {
    .printable { display: block; }
    .non-printable { display: none; }
}
```

and set margin for your page in the print state.

Also check my answer and jsFiddle [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26786460/how-to-open-a-print-dialog-with-a-different-html-content)