# Open print dialog window with different HTML content

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

In order to open a print dialog for the current page, we do something like this:

```
<a href="javascript:window.print()">Print</a>
```

How do you make a link in the current page that will open the print dialog with a different context than the actual page?

---

***Print dialog box in Chrome:***
[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## [Print Dialog](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Printing)

After playing around (and some googling), I came out with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/liormb/3s4g33d9/) solution:

I added a `non-printable` class to the current view and a `printable` class to the printable container element. In my CSS, I used [css media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) where `@media screen` and `@media print` states contains the corresponding display behavior:

```
@media screen {
  .printable { display: none; }
  .non-printable { display: block; }
}

@media print {
  .printable { display: block; }
  .non-printable { display: none; }
}
```

Now, I can print new content from my current view **without** opening a new tab or changing my current view.

Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/liormb/3s4g33d9/) and the [supported browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries)'s list.

Comment: Hey Lior, great answer, what if I want to print a pdf file embedded in an object tag or iframe? Is there a solution in this case? Love the creativity in your answer. It's the best I found on the internet so far!

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if this is actually an answer to your question since your question has very little detail about what you mean by opening a new window.

If you are on /page/one and you want to have a link open /report/page and automatically bring up the print dialog...then that is as easy as triggering `window.print` on the load event, e.g.

```
<body onload='window.print()'>
```

If you don't want that page to always open the print dialog, then make the link to the new page `/report/page?print=1` or something to that effect when you want to print, and when you find that in the URL trigger the onload event.

Comment: Sorry for the VERY late response. `window.print()` is a method that opens the built-in browser print dialog with the current content, which wasn't my intention. I wanted to open the print dialog with a different content than the page has.

Answer (score 2):

There's a nice Javascript plugin called **PrintThis** that accomplishes this very easily.

You just need to use a `jQuery` selector and call the plugin, e.g.:

```
$('selector').printThis();
```

https://github.com/jasonday/printThis

Answer (score 2):

Include printable content in a div. Like:

HTML:

```
<div id='printarea'>
    <p>This is a sample text for printing purpose.</p>
    <input type='button' id='btn' value='Print' onclick='printFunc();'>
</div>
<p>Do not print.</p>
```

JQuery:

```
function printFunc() {
    var divToPrint = document.getElementById('printarea');
    var htmlToPrint = '' +
        '<style type="text/css">' +
        'table th, table td {' +
        'border:1px solid #000;' +
        'padding;0.5em;' +
        '}' +
        '</style>';
    htmlToPrint += divToPrint.outerHTML;
    newWin = window.open("");
    newWin.document.write("<h3 align='center'>Print Page</h3>");
    newWin.document.write(htmlToPrint);
    newWin.print();
    newWin.close();
    }
```

It will just print the printable div.Thanks