# Unable to print div's content using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to print the content of a div when the "Print" button is clicked.
I keep getting this error: "Unable to set value of the property 'innerHTML': object is null or undefined." I read some posts over the Internet but I still can't find a working solution.

Here is my javascript code I use to print (got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468881/print-div-id-printarea-div-only/7532581#7532581)):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function printDiv(divName) {
        var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
        var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

        document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

        window.print();

        document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
    }
</script>
```

My button event raises here:

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonPrint" runat="server" Text="Print »" OnClientClick="printDiv('content');return false"></asp:Button>
```

And this is the div I'm supposed to print:

```
 <div id="content" runat="server">
    <h1 class="title" runat="server" id="formulario"></h1>
    <asp:Table ID="TableForm" runat="server"></asp:Table>
    <div id="TableQuest" runat="server">
    </div>
    <asp:Table ID="TableText" runat="server"></asp:Table>
   <asp:Label ID="LabelInfo" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which line is the error on?

Comment: This line: var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle?

Comment: Ehm sorry..I don't know how to use it..besides..I print the data inside the div from code behind..I don't know how to make it works..

Comment: Can you show the source of the generated HTML and check that it still has an id of 'content'?

Comment: I checked..the name has changed in "<div id="ContentPlaceHolder1_content">", I think it's because I'm using masterpage and content pages, isn't it? Do I have to use the generated ID in order to make it work?

Comment: It works now! I called the method this way:

<asp:Button ID="ButtonStampa" runat="server" Text="Stampa »" OnClientClick="printDiv('ContentPlaceHolder1_content');return false"></asp:Button>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @[Evan Knowles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2137269/evan-knowles) I finally found a solution.

I'm actually using a MasterPage and Content Pages, so my id's name 'content' is automatically changed in 'ContentPlaceHolder1_content'.

If the method is called using the new generated id: `<asp:Button ID="ButtonStampa" runat="server" Text="Stampa »" OnClientClick="printDiv('ContentPlaceHolder1_content');return false"></asp:Button>`
everything works just fine!

Comment: Good job! You may have more luck in future selecting on classes rather than IDs.

Answer (score 0):

**You should use -**  `<%=content.ClientID()%>`

your `Div` is `server side` so you will not get this `div` as you mention in your question. You have to use `.ClientID` as below code.

```
document.getElementById('<%=content.ClientID %>').innerHTML
```

Comment: If I do, I get his error: "The name 'content' does not exist in the current context." Might it be because I'm using a master page (where the javascript code is) and I call the method from a content page?