# show div only when printing

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's say that I have

```
<div id="printOnly">
     <b>Title</b>
     <p>
        Printing content 
     </p>
</div>
```

Is it possible to hide this div when page rendering and to show only when printing this div?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Print <div id=printarea></div> only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468881/print-div-id-printarea-div-only)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need some css for that

```
#printOnly {
   display : none;
}

@media print {
    #printOnly {
       display : block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
@media screen
{
    #printOnly{display:none;}
}

@media print
{
    #printOnly{}
}
```

Comment: As per markup, printOnly is id and you are using class selector in your css.

Answer (score 5):

You should use media query.

In your case:

```
#printOnly {
    display: none;
}

@media print { 
    #printOnly {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

PS take a look here http://www.joshuawinn.com/css-print-media-query/ for browser support

Answer (score 1):

You can attach external css stylesheet with `media="print"` attribute:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution would be to create a wrapper around the non-printable stuff:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">

    #printable { display: none; }

    @media print
    {
        #non-printable { display: none; }
        #printable { display: block; }
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="non-printable">
        Your normal page contents
    </div>

    <div id="printable">
        Printer version
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/*for printer*/
@media print {
    #printOnly { }
        /* write your css rules*/

}
/*for desktop*/
    @media screen {
    #printOnly { display: none;}
             /*for all display view*/                 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@media screen { #printOnly:{display:none;} }
@media print{ #printOnly:{display:block;} }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need media query for switching between print and screen option

```
@media screen { /* for screen option*/

p {

      font-family: verdana, sans-serif;

      font-size: 17px;

  }

   }
```

@media print { /* for print option*/

```
 p {

     font-family: georgia, serif;
     font-size: 14px;
     color: blue;
   }

  }
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp