# print external html using window.print

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.get("http://example.com/invoice.html", function( data ) {
                console.log(data); //work
                window.print(data); // doesn't
            });
```

How to correctly load an external html and print it? Above code doesn't work,

it print the webpage itself, not the external html which I wanted.

Any idea?

Comment: And what's `data`? HTML, JSON, etc?

Comment: @unixarmy it's an html

Answer (score 1):

Print function does not take any parameter, it just print the window data.

As long as your data is html (to be properly formatted and viewed) you can open a new window where you set your data in, close it and use the print function with it since the object will still be available, you can also link any `CSS` specific to the printed data in the new window :

```
$.get("http://example.com/invoice.html", function( data ) {

       var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');
       printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');
       printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
       printWindow.document.write(data);
       printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
       printWindow.document.close();
       printWindow.print();
});
```

Comment: open and close? ok let me try this

Comment: it worked but it blocked by popup, I've seen someone can just print without opening any new window.

Comment: `window.open` is blocked by most popup blockers.

Comment: It does not need to open or to be seen by the user, the browser print view will show the content, this is just a workaround to print specific content.

Comment: You can also check this [trick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468881/print-div-id-printarea-div-only),  you will need to create a printing div, and inside the get function set the html content of this div using jquery `html` then print the main window after setting ur `CSS` as stated in the question (using print media query), this will also do you the trick.

Answer (score 0):

[`window.print()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print) doesn't accept *any* parameters.

You'll need to open the gotten HTML in a new window, or load it into in a modal overlay, then call `window.print`.

Comment: ... or use iframes? :-)

Comment: @unixarmy: That's an option, however: _"Starting with Chrome 45.0 this method is blocked inside an `<iframe>` unless it sandbox attribute has the value allow-modal and the the modal flag is enabled."_

Comment: load the html into and iframe, then print the iframe??

Comment: That's an option, yes.