# Print the content of the DIV using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I'm currently working on a task to print a content in a div. Currently I'm using this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468881/print-div-id-printarea-div-only). This works okay if the div is smaller than the screen. My problem is, my div that I need to print (report) is twice or thrice the height of the normal screen.

When I hit control + P. I can only see is what only captured in the screen.

Comment: which browser you are using..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is sample code sample and hope it will be help you. Feel free to comment if you need additional thing.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#btnPrint").live("click", function () {
            var divContents = $("#dvContainer").html();
            var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');
            printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');
            printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
            printWindow.document.write(divContents);
            printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
            printWindow.document.close();
            printWindow.print();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1">
    <div id="dvContainer">
        This content needs to be printed.
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Print Div Contents" id="btnPrint" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've implemented what you suggested and also added the stylesheet as link. However the stylesheet is not rendering or taking effect on the print preview.

Comment: Are you generating text dynamically

Answer (score 2):

what about using a print query?

```
@media print {
  .selector{
    /*some css*/
  }
}
```

You can use this and re-arrange the content of your `div` in the print process

Comment: I actually used that, the problem is I can only see on the print preview, what is on my screen. My div report has a height of 2-3 screens.

Comment: @Chris you will need to re arrange your components , either by splitting the sheet to 2 columns or change of the content sizes