# problems positioning a jquery.draggable() div for printing with @media print

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, printing

I have a web application that has a draggable div I need to print when the user selects print from the web browser.

The most succinct advice I found so far is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2618980/1467200) stack overflow answer, where it is suggested I make my page invisible and display `#plotArea` only for `@media print` like so:

```
@media print {
    body * {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    #plotArea, #plotArea * {
        visibility: visible;
    }
    #plotArea {
        /* this positioning ignores .draggable() divs */
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;   
        top: 0;
    }
}
```

However, because this div is draggable, I cannot for the life of me remove the offset such that the div positions itself properly for printing. Is it possible to temporarily remove the offset somehow for a draggable div? Below is the div's jquery / css

```
//jquery
$( "#plotArea" ).draggable().offset({ top: 15, left: 400});

/* css */
#plotArea {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 42em;
    height: 54.5em;
    float:left;
    font-size: 12pt;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you are saying is that the draggable plugin is applying inline styling to your `#plotArea` div and therefore overwrites the positioning css you add to it with your print media query?

What you need to do is reset it's positional values for top/left, etc to `auto` and use the `!important` rule overwrite to overwrite the inline styles applied to it via the javascript plugin.

For example;

```
@media print {
    #plotArea {
        left: auto !important;   
        top: auto !important;
    }
}
```