# Printing html content with CSS from remote stylesheet

Tags: html, css, printing

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468881/print-div-id-printarea-div-only/2618980) is a nice trick by Mr. [Bennett McElwee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61754/bennett-mcelwee) to print html content using css `visibility` attribute in `@media print`. But what if the content is styled using remote css files as in [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/d4f497qb/2/).

```
<div class="text-primary">
  Test Tesing Testing
  </div>
```

where `text-primary` class applied from remote bootstrap.css file.

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: text-primary class should make the font color to blue. But in print it is black only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override the Bootstrap `@media print { }`

```
@media print{
    .text-primary{
        color: #337ab7 !important;
    }
}
```

The problem is, that this are the Bootstrap specifications.
The second method is to remove the line from the bootstrap CSS file. (But I think that this is not possible because it is a remote file as you said).