# Print contents of nested divs to printer

Tags: javascript, printing

I have a premium WordPress plugin that embeds PDFs and contains it's own toolbar for the PDFs.

After reaching out to the developer to create a print button for their toolbar, there response was "underwhelming".
"Have the user download the PDF, then print form there".
The developer has the DIVs inside a containing DIV with using only a class, not an ID.

I'm trying to now create my own print button and have it opening the print window, BUT it is not generating a print preview of only the PDF (which is spanning across nested DIVs)

Here is the structure of the rendered HTML output for the target DIVs that I want to print (I want to print all of them, not one at a time).

My problem is that the window. print function is not capturing only the content of the DIVs. It's previewing the whole webpage.

```
<div class="pdfemb-pagescontainer">
    <div class="pdfemb-inner-div pdfemb-page1">
        <canvas class="pdfemb-the-canvas">
        </canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="pdfemb-inner-div pdfemb-page2">
        <canvas class="pdfemb-the-canvas">
        </canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="pdfemb-inner-div pdfemb-page3">
        <canvas class="pdfemb-the-canvas">
        </canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my current code:

```
<button onclick="printPDF()">Print Lesson PDF</button>
<script>
    function printPDF() {
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("pdfemb-pagescontainer");
        window.print(x[0].innerHTML);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: window.print() takes no arguments

Comment: @Jonasw So I had noticed. This is why i'm seeking a solution form the JS Gods :)

Answer (score 0):

You dont need js for that. Some css should do it:

```
@media print {
  body * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .pdfemb-pagescontainer, .pdfemb-pagescontainer * {
    visibility: visible;
   }
  .pdfemb-pagescontainer {
    position: absolute !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    top: 0 !important;
  }
}
```

Now you can do:

```
window.print();
```

and it automatically hides all around...

[based on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468881/print-div-id-printarea-div-only)

Comment: This produces a print preview of 1 blank page, the contents of the first DIV, then one more blank page. I'm asking about printing all DIVs.

Comment: @dennis could you try the updated code? And is there html missing in your code?

Comment: I have no missing HTML in my code above. Putting !important after the left and top still produced a print window with 3 pages, page 1 is blank, page 2 has the page 1 DIV contents, and page 3 is blank.

Thanks for trying.

Comment: @Dennis but basically it is kinda working right? then go to the dev consoles tab which shows a dom tree, and hack around with css until it looks like you expect it to. then copy that css into a media print {} block and it should work...

Answer (score 0):

```
function PrintDiv(divClass, title)
{
    var custom_window = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=400,width=600');

    custom_window.document.write('<html><head><title>' + title  + '</title></head>');
    custom_window.document.write('<body>' + document.getElementsByClassName(divClass)[0].innerHTML + '</body></html>');
    custom_window.print();
    custom_window.close();

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Youre missing either a [0] or a loop

Comment: Yeah, I added it, (if yo have many classes with same class name - you can use "document.getElementById()"

Comment: @LesukAlexey As I mentioned in my description, I am limited to using classes, ID's are not an option.

Comment: @LesukAlexey although this seems promising, the issue is with the class name "pdfemb-pagescontainer". This seems cause it to not function. I cannot change the class name.

Comment: @Dennis the issue is actually with the canvas element. it cant be simply copied..