# How to print a html page with header and footer on all pages?

Tags: html, css

would like some help as i m trying to print the html page. I would like to have the header and the footer on all pages when printing.

this is my current code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <style media="screen">
      .header{
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        height: 100px;
      }
      .content{

      }
      .footer{
        padding-top: 50px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
      }
    </style>

    <div class="header">
      header
    </div>

    <div class="content">
      <table>
        <tr><td>dfdsfsdfsdf start</td></tr>
        <tr><td>dfdsfsdfsdf</td></tr>
        <tr><td>dfdsfsdfsdf</td></tr>
        <tr><td>dfdsfsdfsdf end</td></tr>
        <!-- there will be around 1000 record of  <tr><td></td></tr>-->
      </table>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
      footer
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

currently the header is not in the second page and the footer goes to the second page and there is no footer for the first page. So how can i do it so that it will look like a bank statement or any other statement where on every page there is a header and a footer and the value from the table remains in the middle of every page

[Here is the image which i m getting currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDifb.png)
[Here is the image which i m getting currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U99mh.png)

Comment: you know, add it on all the pages?

Comment: because the table <tr><td>dfdsfsdfsdf start</td></tr> is a lot so thats why. I have like 1000 record

Comment: possible duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468881/print-div-id-printarea-div-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468881/print-div-id-printarea-div-only)

Answer (score 0):

You may just want to provide the data as a downloadable .pdf or .doc, and configure that file to have a header and footer on each page. That's what my bank does with my statements.

I don't think HTML5 supports what you're trying to do. Though it would be cool feature for HTML6.

Comment: i dont get it. what do you mean ya?

Comment: I mean take all the data you're going to put in your table and put it in a Microsoft Word document. Then add a header and footer to it in Word, and make that document available for the user to download from your webpage