# Print selected part from body

Tags: javascript, html

I want to print the body which only includes the selected part

on click of this method the page alignment changes

//app

```
<div class="header">
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Page</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="payment-receipt">
    <div>
        <p>Price$24.78</p>
        <p>Product Status About to reach </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

//js

```
 printDiv() {
     //Get the HTML of div
     var divElements = document.getElementById('payment-receipt').innerHTML;
     //Get the HTML of whole page
     var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;
     //Reset the page's HTML with div's HTML only
     document.body.innerHTML = "<html><head><title></title></head><body>" + divElements + "</body>";
     //Print Page
     window.print();
     //Restore orignal HTML
     document.body.innerHTML = oldPage;  
}
```

The alignments should stay same before the click and after the click of method

Comment: I think it would be better to solve this by using css styling for print

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468881/print-div-id-printarea-div-only

Comment: Use @media print

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by using [print stylesheet](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp)

```css
@media print{
  /* hide this element on media print */
  .header{
    display:none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Page</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="payment-receipt">
   <div>
      <p>Price$24.78</p>
      <p>Product Status About to reach </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="header">
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Page</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="payment-receipt" name='clickf'>
   <div>
      <p>Price$24.78</p>
      <p>Product Status About to reach </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

> Print selected part using javascript no jquery

```
var el = document.getElementById('payment-receipt');
if(el){
  el.addEventListener('click', print_div, false);
}

function print_div(){
    var content = document.getElementById('payment-receipt').innerHTML;
    var mywindow = window.open();
    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Print</title></head><body >'+content+'</body></html>');
    mywindow.print();
        document.body.innerHTML =content;  
         mywindow.close();
    return true;
}
```

[working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4byx82g3/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Younes Zaidi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6802333/younes-zaidi) answer with a small change :

[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/AmirHz/xqo6yrwL/2/)

```js
var el = document.getElementById('payment-receipt');
if(el){
  el.addEventListener('click', print_div, false);
}

function print_div(){
    var content = document.getElementById('payment-receipt').innerHTML;
    var mywindow = window.open();
    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Print</title></head><body >'+ window.getSelection() +'</body></html>');
    mywindow.print();
  document.body.innerHTML =content;  
    return true;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Page</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="payment-receipt" name='clickf'>
   <div>
      <p>Price$24.78</p>
      <p>Product Status About to reach </p>
   </div>
</div>


<textarea id="text"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem - There was a form containing user data. I had to print that form but also prevent  print unnecessary data or say only print a specific portion of the page that contains data

How i solved this

**1. For Simple Cases**
 Hide all the elements that you don't need and call the window.print() on the remaining part

```
printForm(){

    document.getElementById('element1').style.display='None'
    document.getElementById('element2').style.display='None'
    document.getElementById('element2').style.display='None'
    window.print()
}
```

**2. For Complex Cases**
Now there might be a problem in complex dom, in my case it was simple, now let's see how to solve the same in complex dom structure

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div id="content">

   <!-- Content that has to be printed -->   

  </div>

  <div id="print-content">

  <!-- Will be used for printing purpose -->

  </div>
</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
let contentEl = document.getElementById('content')
let printEl = document.getElementById('print-content')

printEl.appencChild(contentEl.innerHtml)
contentEl.style.display = "None"

window.print()
```