# Why does document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML not get canvas element?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

so i am trying to print a div with canvas element using a basic JavaScript onClick function.
This div has canvas and other HTML elements.

any idea how i can print this div without .

PS: inner.HTML completely strips off the canvas element and gets the others.
The output is supposed to show a signed signature within the canvas tag but rather displays only sign here?

```
function printDiv(divName){
             var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
             var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

             document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

             window.print();

             document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
        }
```

HTML

```
<div id="divName">
<span>Sign below</span>

<canvas></canvas>

</div>

<button id="print" name="print" onclick="printDiv('divName')"> PRINT </button>
```

Comment: CSS Print Media, use it to hide the content you do not want to show up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print <div id="printarea"></div> only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468881/print-div-id-printarea-div-only)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your question is most likely a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468881/print-div-id-printarea-div-only) following question, I will try to answer it anyway:

The `div.innerHTML()` Function just provides the raw inner HTML-Value - this doesn't work with the canvas element, because it is not storing its content in raw XML.

However, there are better solutions for printing than javascript: CSS contains a `@media print` selector, which allows you to hide all elements except the canvas, for example.

The code is made from the answer from [the question i referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468881/print-div-id-printarea-div-only):

CSS:

```
@media print {
  body * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  #divName, #divName * {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  #divName {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

A Basic introduction into CSS can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_intro.asp)