# How to print a Component in Vaadin?

Tags: vaadin

I have been struggling for sometime now, trying to find ways to print out/generate document using vaadin.
i have tried using the below code but this prints all the components. I wanted to print only a particular form or layout.

```java
UI.getCurrent().getElement().executeJs("print();")
```

Can some one guide me?

Comment: What version? v8 has functions to write out the HTM e..g

Comment: using v14 @cfrick

Answer (score 3):

You'll need some CSS (similar to the approach mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2618980/11982497)) that will hide everything when printing is invoked, except for the Layout or Component that needs to be printed.

For example, assuming you have the following two DIVs in your view:

```
Div printable = new Div(new Span("printable"));
Div nonPrintable = new Div(new Span("nonPrintable"));
```

You can give one of those a classname:

```
printable.addClassName("printable");
```

Then, you would add the following CSS to the global scope:

```
@media print {
  body, body * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .printable, .printable * {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  .printable {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

**Note**, in a Vaadin 14 project, the previous CSS is most easily incorporated using the `@CssImport` annotation. For example, the following annotations can be added to one of your Java classes:

```
@CssImport("./shared-styles.css")
```

Then under the directory `{projecr-root-directory}/frontend`, you'd need to create `shared-styles.css` and place the aforementioned styling there.