# How do I print a specific area in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How do I make javascript print a specific part of a text?
every time I try to use the print() command it prints the entire page if I do print("MYTEXT") it does not work? how do I do this or is it impossible?

Comment: Can you put the text in an element? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468881/print-div-id-printarea-div-only

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you! It has worked and printing only the `div` thank you!