# CSS not loading when I call a div to print

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div that I would like to print, but when I call it, the CSS doesn't apply. I got the JS from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468881/print-div-id-printarea-div-only). It's supposed to print just the table, which it does, but It doesn't apply the styles for the table, and it ends up unformatted.

#### Expected result

[image: Expected result]

#### Actual result

[image: Actual result]

#### My code

```js
function printDiv(divName) {
  var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
  var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

  document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

  window.print();

  document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```

```css
.table-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  justify-content: center;
}

table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

th {
  font-size: 20px;
}

td {
  font-size: 15px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.total1 {
  border: none;
}

.pc-border-title {
  text-align: center;
}

.intro-heading {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.pcbuilder-link {
  color: #cecece;
}

.pcbuilder-link:hover {
  color: #adadad;
}

.table-heading {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
}

#printableArea {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.table-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  justify-content: center;
}

table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

th {
  font-size: 20px;
}

td {
  font-size: 15px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.total1 {
  border: none;
}

.pc-border-title {
  text-align: center;
}

.intro-heading {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.pcbuilder-link {
  color: #cecece;
}

.pcbuilder-link:hover {
  color: #adadad;
}

.table-heading {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
}

#printableArea {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="printableArea">
  <h3 class="table-heading" contenteditable="true">My PC Setup</h3>
  <table spellcheck="false">
    <tr>
      <!--https://pcbuilder.net/rigs/aK6rMH/-->
      <th>Part</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Notes</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Processor</td>
      <td contenteditable="true" onclick="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)">AMD Ryzen 9 7950X
      </td>
      <td contenteditable="true" onclick="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)" class="price">
        747</td>
      <td contenteditable="true" onclick="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)">
        32-Thread<br>16-Core<br>4.5GHz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Motherboard</td>
      <td contenteditable="true" onclick="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)">GIGABYTE X670E AORme Master
      </td>
      <td contenteditable="true" onclick="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)" class="price">
        542.84</td>
      <td contenteditable="true" onclick="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)">Socket: AM5
        <br>RAM Slots: 4<br>Chipset: AMD X670E</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>CPU Cooler</td>
      <td contenteditable="true" onclick="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)">Cooler Master Hyper 212 EVO V2</td>
      <td contenteditable="true" onclick="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)" class="price">
        90</td>
      <td contenteditable="true" onclick="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)">Side Panel: Tempered Glass, Steel<br>Cabinet Type: ATX Full Tower</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Case</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" onclick="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)">NZXT H510 - CA-H510B-B1
        </td>
        <td contenteditable="true" onclick="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)" class="price">
          1,584.90</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" onclick="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)">Memory: 24GB
          <br>Chipset: GeForce RTX 3090 Ti<br>Interface: PCIe 4.0 x16</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Graphics card</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" onclick="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)">Nvidia RTX 3090 TI Founders Edition</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" onclick="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)" class="price">
          51.44</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" onclick="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)">Fan Speed: 650RPM-1800RPM
          <br>Noise Level: 8-27dBA</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>RAM</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" onclick="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)">G.Skill Trident Z5 RGB Series 32GB 2 x 16GB (x2)</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" onclick="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)" class="price">
          564.42</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" onclick="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)">RAM Size: 64GB
          <br>RAM Type: DDR5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Storage (SSD)</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" onclick="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)">Samsung EVO 970 1TB
        </td>
        <td contenteditable="true" onclick="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)" class="price">
          167.99</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" onclick="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)">Capacity: 1 TB
          <br>Type: SSD<br>Cache Memory: 1024 MB</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Storage (HDD)</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" onclick="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)">Seagate BarraCuda 2TB
        </td>
        <td contenteditable="true" onclick="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)" class="price">
          53.49</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" onclick="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)">Capacity: 2 TB
          <br>Type: HDD<br>RPM: 7200 RPM<br>Interface: SATA 6 Gb/s<br>Cache Memory: 256 MB</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Case Cooler</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" onclick="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)">ARCTIC P12
        </td>
        <td contenteditable="true" onclick="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)" class="price">
          5.73</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" onclick="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)">Fan RPM: 1800 RPM
          <br>Airflow: 56.3 CFM<br>Noise Level: N/A</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Power Supply</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" onclick="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)">Thermaltake Smart 430W
        </td>
        <td contenteditable="true" onclick="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)" class="price">
          98.95</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" onclick="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)">Power: 430W
          <br>Efficiency: 80+</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Monitor</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" onclick="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)">Acer SB220Q Bi 21.5
        </td>
        <td contenteditable="true" onclick="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)" class="price">
          170</td>
        <td contenteditable="true" onclick="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)">Screen Size: 21.5"
          <br>Response Time: 4ms<br>Resolution: 1920 x 1080<br>Refresh Rate: 75 Hz</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="total1"><b>Total</b></td>
        <td class="total1"></td>
        <td class="total1"></td>
        <td contenteditable="true" onclick="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)" class="price">
          <b>4,077</b>
        </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="printDiv('printableArea')" value="Print your setup" />
```

How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: Why is there a slash before `#printableArea`?

Comment: sounds like you need to style for print, you can read more here https://www.sitepoint.com/css-printer-friendly-pages/ this may solve your issue. so one style sheet for screen and one for print in the media of your linked css type thing.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem while printing table using similar javascript function.  You have to provide all css to the print window as well. I am pasting my code here.  You will have to modify that to suit your requirements.

```
    function PrintElem(elem)
    {
        var orgPrint = document.getElementById(elem).innerHTML;
        document.querySelectorAll(".no-print").forEach(el => el.remove()); // removes some elements from the table that are not to be pronted
        var toPrint = document.getElementById(elem).innerHTML;
        var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=400,width=600');

        mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>My Title</title>');
        mywindow.document.write('<style>');
        mywindow.document.write('* { font-family: Roboto, \'Segoe UI\', Tahoma, sans-serif; }');
        mywindow.document.write('#invTable { border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }');
        mywindow.document.write('#invTable td, #invTable th { border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 8px; }');
        mywindow.document.write('.text-end { text-align: right !important; }');
        mywindow.document.write('.text-center {text-align: center !important; }');
        mywindow.document.write('body {    display: flex;    flex-direction: column;}');
        mywindow.document.write('.print-footer { margin-top: auto; position:fixed; bottom:0;text-align: center; width:100%; border-top: 1px solid #ddd; }');
        mywindow.document.write('</style>');

        mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        mywindow.document.write('<br/><br/><br/>');
        mywindow.document.write(toPrint);
        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

        mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
        mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/

        mywindow.print();
        mywindow.close();
        
        document.getElementById(elem).innerHTML = orgPrint; // restores the table as is 

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: @roy that's just a byproduct of pasting my code in a code block, I forgot to remove it. Shouldn't affect anything in my actual code, though