# Print a component in React: NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf-generation

I want to print a Component using JavaScript in React ( NextJS project ) using this function from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468881/print-div-id-printarea-div-only).

```js
  const print = () => {
    var printContents = document?.getElementById("div")?.innerHTML
    var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML

    document.body.innerHTML = printContents as string

    window.print()

    document.body.innerHTML = originalContents
  }
```

It displays the PDF Preview in the first click but when I click on the print button second time it throws this error:

`

NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.
`

[image]

This is my full code :

```
import { Divider } from "@tremor/react"
import { useRef } from "react"
import React from "react"
import { useReactToPrint } from "react-to-print"

import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button"
import { Sheet, SheetContent, SheetHeader, SheetTrigger } from "@/components/ui/sheet"

import { BuildingInformation } from "./components/building-information"
import { EnergyEfficiency } from "./components/energy-efficiency"
import { FinancialAnalysis } from "./components/financial-analysis"
import { Intro } from "./components/Intro"
import { Modernization } from "./components/modernization"

export const DataReporting = () => {
  const print = () => {
    var printContents = document?.getElementById("div")?.innerHTML
    var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML

    document.body.innerHTML = printContents as string

    window.print()

    document.body.innerHTML = originalContents
  }

  return (
    <Sheet>
      <SheetTrigger>
        <Button variant={"ghost"}>Holen Sie sich Ihren Bericht</Button>
      </SheetTrigger>
      <SheetContent
        side={"bottom"}
        className='h-full m-auto overflow-y-auto print:overflow-y-auto sm:w-screen lg:w-fit'
      >
        <SheetHeader>
          <Button className='w-fit z-20 mr-auto bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-600' onClick={print}>
            Herunterladen
          </Button>
          <Divider />
        </SheetHeader>
        <div id='div'>
          <Intro />
          <BuildingInformation />
          <Modernization />
          <EnergyEfficiency />
          <FinancialAnalysis />
        </div>
      </SheetContent>
    </Sheet>
  )
}
```

Comment: Manipulating the DOM directly would cause discrepancies as pointed out in the comments of the thread you have mentioned.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe, create another temporary `div` element to hold the `printContents`. Then you can print and delete the temporary `div` so as to not play around with the DOM.